# events `messageUpdate` and `messageDelete` doesn't "work" after bot restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Well, events `messageUpdate` and `messageDelete` doesn't "work" after restarting the bot

I mean, they don't respond to messages that were sent before the restart

I added MESSAGE to partials

Now the events works, but there is a problem with the `if (newMessage.author.bot) return` and `if (message.author.bot) return` and generally with `message|newMessage.author|member` etc.

Here are the error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bot')
    at module.exports.run (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\events\messageDelete.js:14:28)
    at Slodziak.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\aslodziak.js:40:43)
    at Slodziak.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Slodziak.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at MessageDeleteAction.handle (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageDelete.js:24:16)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_DELETE] (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_DELETE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:346:31)    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:478:22)        
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:317:10)       
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak\Slodziak13vCanary\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
```

Can someone help? I need these partials MESSAGE to messageUpdate because the bot did not respond to messages that were sent after restart. More specifically, to the automod, i.e. that it deletes invitations if someone has edited the message and has no permissions

`messageUpdate`

```
module.exports = class {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    async run(oldMessage, newMessage) {

        const data = {};
        const client = this.client;
        data.config = client.config;

        if (newMessage.author.bot) return;
        if (!newMessage.editedAt) return;

        code that deleted invites if member has not permissions

    }
};
```

`messageDelete`

```
module.exports = class {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    async run(message) {

        const data = {};
        const client = this.client;
        data.config = client.config;

        if (message.author.bot) return;

        Code that snipes deleted message
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post some relevant code. Could you update your question?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Idk why but done

Comment: Because I wanted to see how you use partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `newMessage.author` is `null`. You already knew that you would need to use the `MESSAGE` partials.

The problem is that you don't check if the received message is a partial only.

A partial message will not contain all of the original `Message` parameters. The `id`, the `channelId`, and the `guildId` will be present, but others, like `author`, can be `null`.

To solve this, you'll need to check if your message is partial only, and if it is, you can [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch) it and use it as usual:

```js
module.exports = class {
  constructor(client) {
    this.client = client;
  }
  async run(oldMessage, newMessage) {
    const data = {};
    const client = this.client;
    data.config = client.config;
    
    if (oldMessage.partial) oldMessage = await oldMessage.fetch();
    if (newMessage.partial) newMessage = await newMessage.fetch();

    if (newMessage.author.bot) return;
    if (!newMessage.editedAt) return;

    // code that deleted invites if the member has no permissions
  }
};
```

Comment: How do I fix a error in messageDelete? message.fetch() doesn't work

Comment: You can't fetch a deleted message. You can use [audit logs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#who-deleted-a-message)